# Why is "all" appended to my custom build command in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

I'm using Eclipse CDT on Debian and I want to specify my own build command. I have done so in the preferences:

[image: Screenshot of build command]

As you can see, my build command is `g++ -std=gnu++11 main.cpp -o main -lGL -lGLU -lglut`.

---

...As a side question, is `-std=gnu++11` redundant? I'm using a fresh install of Debian and `sudo apt-get install build-essentials`.

---

For some reason, however, Eclipse doesn't exactly use my build command. Instead, it appends `all` to the end of it, which screws things up:

[image: Screenshot of build output]

As you can see, Eclipse appended `all` to the end of my build command, screwing things up. I believe there is some setting to disable this in Eclipse, but I can't find it for the life of me and my google skills aren't cutting it either.

How can I disable this?

Comment: The builder settings expect some command like `make`, which would  expect a particular build target (`all` by default). If you want to change the toolchain, go to the toolchain editor instead. Also all of these compiler specific options should be edited/set in the project properties c++ build settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually want to edit the builder settings page to provide the compiler/linker specific option settings.

Well you can remove the `all` appended on the next tab page

[image]

But I'm pretty sure that's not what you should do. You can provide all the compiler specific options, include directories, additional libraries etc. at the `C/C++ Build->Settings` pages:

[image]

Comment: I am also facing this "all" appended issue.
In my eclipse, under c/c++ > settings, I don't see any compiler options, rather two tabs "Binary Parsers" and "Error Parsers" and also configuration is disabled and can not be changed.

Comment: Thank you, just as a tip for others: The textfield after "Build (incrementa build)" was blank for me, but still added "all" to my build command. It worked to add some dummy text, build, remove the dummy text and then build again.